# VMware network adapter problems after windows update

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware

I recently updated my pc from windows 8.1 to windows 10 and i have problem with my virtual machine(vmware). My virtual machine runs kali linux and cannot find network adapters to establish connection to internet. I try fix this problem with Virtual Network Editor in vmware folder, but i can not find it.How to solve this?? Help me please

Answer (score 0):

I recently updated my PC from a Windows 7 to Windows 10 and I got the same problem. Doing some research on the web someone suggested to run the installer in Repair mode followed by a restart of the OS (Windows 10). I did that and it worked for me, so that is what I'll suggest you should do.

Comment: i think i found the problem. reinstall vmware without delete your virtual-machine and the vmware adapters should work perfectly. That i did and it works.

Comment: @johnminister05Minister well you still can put that as an answer to your question so other users might see it as such!